# Put loading in email sending

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have email function that send 5 person at one time. I call this function in controller called `submitemail`. I want to put loading when the email function triggered. I want to show message to user that email sending is successful or not. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call your controller's action with ajax...show a loading image before ajax call...and hide the loading image in oncomplete event of ajax function...and also show appropriate success and error message.

Comment: Thanks Ankush, is there any example or sample for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822038/display-loading-gif-image-while-loading-with-ajax

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", null, new AjaxOptions
            {UpdateTargetId = "dialog-model", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
            }, new { id ="AjaxForm" }))
{
...form here
}
```

AjaxOptions is an object that can get succes in succes you can show message

```
new AjaxOptions()
 {
     UpdateTargetId = "divPlaceholder",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
     OnSuccess = "alert('OnSuccess')",
     OnBegin = "alert('OnBegin')",
     OnComplete = "alert('OnComplete')",
     OnFailure = "alert('OnFailure')"

 }
```